# How to find which of the files do not exist given the list of absolute paths in unix

Tags: file, unix, directory

I have a list of absolute file paths as shown below. This list includes 1000's of files in different directories and some of the files are missing. I want to know which files are missing. How can we do this in unix?

list of files:
files.txt

```
/filpath1/file.bam
/filespath2/file2.bam
/filepath3/file3.bam
```

Comment: Do you know that `/filpath1/file.bam\n/filespath2/file2.bam` is 2 files, and not a single file with an embedded newline?

Comment: @William Pursell that is right! there are three files and say if one of them is missing, I want to identify the missing file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will probably work (it fails if any of the files contain embedded new lines, amongst other possible failure scenarios):

```
while read path; do
  test -e "$path" || echo "$path" does not exist
done < files.txt
```